# how to parse arguments from console and check if they are valid in a method

Tags: java

My code worked when it was in the main method, but once I try to put it in its own method, I get "args cannot be resolved to a variable" Also, I am very new to java, is there a way to simplify this code block, I have a book that shows modularized code, but it is not explained in detail.

```
 private static boolean validateInput() {

    //if invalid character is entered ie. a letter, will go to the catch
    try 
    {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);          
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Input #1 is not a valid integer.");
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Input #2 is not a valid integer.");
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Input #3 is not a valid integer.");
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your `String[] args` as a parameter to `validateInput()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (validateInput(args)) {
        ...
    }
}

private static boolean validateInput(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `args` to the method, otherwise it doesn't know what it is.

Re-declare you `validateInput` method as

```
private static boolean validateInput(String[] args) {
```

From you main method, call it like....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...Pre init...
    boolean isValid = validateInput(args);
    //...Post init...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 private static boolean validateInput() {
```

to

```
  private static boolean validateInput(String[] args) {
```

and call it in `main` as

```
     boolean result = validateInput(args);
```